# Rest Api: best way to use universal unique identifiers(uuid) instead of Auto-Increment primary key

Tags: api, rest, uuid

This is my first time building a rest api using php laravel framework and i have noticed that, for security and business purpose it's important to use universal unique identifiers(uuid): [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12378220/api-design-and-security-why-hide-internal-ids) . As one of the great php developer mentioned his book.

> One important factor with auto-incrementing ID’s is that anyone with access to your API will know exactly how many resources you have, which might not be a statistic you want your competitors to have - Phil Sturgeon.

If I use 32 characters long uuid then my url will be look something like this: https://example-api.com/users/jeta-4063a267-efd8-5377-9014-864f639c82ea where if i use     auto-increment key it will look simple: https://example-api.com/users/1. My question is it ok if the url looks weird like that or is there any way to use uuid.

Answer (score 1):

It is OK if the URL looks weird like that. In most cases, people won't be typing out your URL by hand .. either the client will generate the URL, or it will be copied and pasted by an end user.