# Resources ID in REST Api = primary key in database

Tags: mysql, rest

I am creating a RESTful API.

My table of e.g. users has a primary key 1,2,3, ...

Now to name my resources in the API I want some more complex name. A hash of something which also will be a unique identifier but a little more difficult to guess.

Should I save this hash in an extra column in my user table or kick the 1,2,3, ... out of the primary key and use the unique hash as global id (database & API)

Comment: Is the intention to obfuscate/hide the internal ID? If yes, why?

Comment: I think you should use only a single PK, so use the hash as PK and remove the numeric id. Btw. it does not really matter, the only difference that the numeric id is guessable while the hash id is non guessable, but slower (depending on the db).

Comment: @inf3rno using a hash as PK might have a severe detrimental effect in insert performance in some databases. MySQL, for instance, scales very, very poorly with a random PK.

Comment: @PedroWerneck You are right, by mysql it is better to use something else as pk and add uuid only as unique index: http://www.percona.com/blog/2014/12/19/store-uuid-optimized-way/ (I don't like that db :D)

Comment: pls add some upvote to the question as well.

Comment: Another discussion here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/218306/why-not-expose-a-primary-key

Answer (score 8):

So, from the API perspective, the only sane reason I can imagine for doing something like that is avoiding a strong coupling between the URIs and the PK. Like, for instance, you expect to change storage in the future and you don't want to be stuck with a sequential PK forever. If that's the case, I'd say to use a random UUID Version 4, store as a binary value in the database, and use the hex representation to construct the URI. That's what I did in this situation and it works fine.

Now, from the database perspective, I would recommend checking how your database deals with random values as primary key before adopting that. For instance, MySQL insert performance degrades terribly with random values in the clustered index, and it's better to have an unique index for the hash/uuid column, and an auto-increment column as PK.

Other than that, if all you want is to obfuscate the URI, I wouldn't change the database, and simply apply some reversible encoding to the integer value, to use it as part of the URI.

Answer (score 7):

Why the complexity?

[REST API URLs are meant to be discoverable](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/170695/what-is-the-need-for-discoverability-in-a-rest-api-when-the-clients-are-not-ad). Obfuscating the resource identifier is anything but discoverable. If you want to keep people from accessing certain data, then secure that data through authentication and authorization. If you're really creating a RESTful API, part of that is discoverability.

Comment: I never understood why people need non-guessable ids by REST. Maybe another layer of security, I don't know.

Comment: @inf3rno It's a bad idea; if you have a REST API, you want people to able to easily ascertain how to use it. That's the first consideration (otherwise, don't make it a RESTful API).  The problem with obfuscation is that it provides no extra security and it makes your API ugly. Why do that to your user?

Comment: I don't think so, I think there is no significant difference between an auto inc integer and a random string id. People (developers) who use it do not care, because they access the id property for example in a JSON, or they use the given URIs / URI templates, which already contain the id part or use the id property. Non guessable ids give a slight resource protection in exchange for a small speed decrease.

Comment: @inf3rno Very slight. When you take into account development time to debug and figure out which IDs correspond to which Hash, you realize you're wasting far more development hours on something that doesn't help you than you are gaining security.

Comment: Actually I was talking about using string ids instead of numeric ids in the database as well. E.g. mongodb does the same. I think id mapping does not worth the effort.

Comment: I usually don't upvote answers that simply challenge the question, but this one makes a valid point.

Comment: I agree about discoverability, but I think that is not predictable IDs but more HATEOAS. However I think there is a reason to not expose PK, and that is possible migrations which might change PKs and therefore mix selected resources. However there might be performance issues indexing and fetching  UUIDv4 resources.

Comment: these answers explain pretty well the importance of hiding internal ids: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12378220/api-design-and-security-why-hide-internal-ids