# mysql auto increment from 00001 - 99999 and reset the value every year

Tags: mysql, node.js

My first aim is to generate customer reference code automaticaly everytime when I insert a new customer

so when it shown in my nodejs it should be : "MS2200001"

So my idea is set id from customer table (mysql) with auto increment and zerofill (int)
length = 5

So I can get id 00001
and insert to another column named as "customer reference"
with

```
("MS" + (2022)+ "00001")
```

And I am trying to reset the counter to 00001 again if become 2023,2024,2025 etc.

How can I archive this in phpmyadmin or I should chnage my idea?

[image]

Comment: " (int) length = 5" that's not what `int(5)` does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892341/what-does-int5-in-mysql-mean

Comment: 'so when it shown in my nodejs it should be : "MS2200001" '  if the reference code is for the customer to see you'll protect yourself from social engineering and phishing by giving your customers unguessable codes instead.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12378220/api-design-and-security-why-hide-internal-ids/

Comment: (int) length = 5" that's not what int(5) alright I will take a look at there

'so when it shown in my nodejs it should be : "MS2200001" ' if the reference code is for the customer to see you'll protect yourself from social engineering and phishing by giving your customers unguessable codes instead, this is a mangement system for self use

Comment: Use trigger-generating technique and additional MyISAM table with secondary AI column in PK.

Comment: @Akina I have no idea what is this, am a newbie

Answer (score 0):

Use trigger-generating technique and additional MyISAM table with secondary AUTO_INCREMENT column in PRIMARY KEY.

An example:

```sql
-- base table for complete identifier generation
CREATE TABLE base_for_complete_id (
    `year` YEAR, 
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`year`, id)
) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

```sql
-- create trigger which will generate complete identifier
CREATE TRIGGER generate_complete_id
BEFORE INSERT ON maintable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE tmp INT;
    -- insert row into base table
    INSERT INTO base_for_complete_id (`year`) VALUES (YEAR(NEW.created_at));
    -- store id generated for current year
    SET tmp = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    -- save generated complete identifier into main table
    SET NEW.complete_id = CONCAT('prefix_', YEAR(NEW.created_at), '_', tmp);
    -- clear excess rows from base table
    DELETE FROM base_for_complete_id WHERE `year` = YEAR(NEW.created_at) AND id < tmp;
END
```

[DEMO fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2b215eddbb5bc5986251cfaa22492737)

If you need to format `id` part of generated value with leading zeros then use [`LPAD()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad), for example `SET tmp = LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 5, 0);`.

Caution! If the value for generated number exceeds 99999 then it will be truncated, and only 5 leading digits will be stored.